# Commands and triggers for updating transitive dependencies using yarn

Tags: transitive-dependency, yarn-v2

I have a slight trouble understanding what are all possible yarn commands/triggers/situations that can lead to upgrading of transitive dependencies. Epecially I'm interested will yarn upgrade -E library-x -command also upgrade the transitive dependencies of this library-x and if so in what situations? Am I correct that the transitive dependencies would be upgraded by this command only if there would have happened a change in the version numbering in the reference to a f.e. library-y inside library-x (library-y being sub-library to library-x and practically a transitive library for my application I'm installing library-x by running the yarn upgrade command). So, f.e. if library-x has library-y defined in package.json dependencies using caret ^1.0.0 and it would get updated to ^1.0.1 in the new version of library-x, let's say 2.0.1 that I would be installing. Would this change work as trigger updating this transitive dependency in my application when I run yarn upgrade -E library-x@2.0.1 at the time I would have had 2.0.0 already installed? And if the latest version of library-y would be f.e. 1.99.99, would it be then this version what would be installed as transitive dependency as it would be the latest allowed version defined by the caret definition in library-x (^1.0.1)?

Also, I have heard rumours that it would be possible to update transitive dependencies despite there would not have been any change in the way library-x would have referenced it's sub-dependency (the reference would have remained ^1.0.0 between library-x update from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1). Am I correct that in this case yarn upgrade -E library-x@2.0.1 command would not update library-y transitive dependency, but I could update this library-y transitive dependency (and all the possible other transitive dependencies) by running a command yarn upgrade library-x right after running yarn upgrade -E library-x@2.0.1.?

Surely I would be intereted to understand all about possible triggers and commands how to update transitive dependencies, but I have just slightly struggled finding any comprehensive guide related to this topic, but these above questions are the ones I have mostly interested lately.